# Rhythmbox and Conky do not work together but they work individually

Tags: rhythmbox, conky

I'm using `hardy-conky` on my laptop running 12.10 and on my main PC running saucy 13.10

Neither are able to run Rhythm Box and `conky` at the same time. I run rhythm box and conky disappears. I close rhythm box and `conky` reappears.

The program never crashes. This is important. The `conky` process continues running it just disappears for some reason.

There's no update from the terminal I'm running conky in.

Here's my `conkyrc` :

Tried to google this but there's nothing on the issue which is hilarious.

I have looked through my `conkyrc` and removed anything under the if rhythmbox part. All that was in there was some script to look for a `lyricsdownloader`

```
##################################################################################
## Conky by http://jameshardy88.deviantart.com/art/Conky-JamesHardy88-122466724 ##
##          Modified by Umair - http://www.NoobsLab.com         ##
##################################################################################
# Use Xft?
use_xft yes
xftfont DejaVu Sans:size=8
xftalpha 0.8
text_buffer_size 2048

# Update interval in seconds
update_interval 1

# This is the number of times Conky will update before quitting.
# Set to zero to run forever.
total_run_times 0

# Create own window instead of using desktop (required in nautilus)
own_window yes
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_type conky
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

# Use double buffering (reduces flicker, may not work for everyone)
double_buffer yes

# Minimum size of text area
minimum_size 160 0
#maximum_width 200

# Draw shades?
draw_shades no

# Draw outlines?
draw_outline no

# Draw borders around text
draw_borders no

# Stippled borders?
stippled_borders 0

# border margins
border_margin 5

# border width
border_width 1

# Default colors and also border colors
default_color FFFFFF
#default_shade_color black
#default_outline_color white
own_window_colour white

# Text alignment, other possible values are commented
#alignment top_left
alignment top_right
#alignment bottom_left
#alignment bottom_right

# Gap between borders of screen and text
# same thing as passing -x at command line
gap_x 15
gap_y 20

# Subtract file system buffers from used memory?
no_buffers yes

# set to yes if you want all text to be in uppercase
uppercase no

# number of cpu samples to average
# set to 1 to disable averaging
cpu_avg_samples 1

# number of net samples to average
# set to 1 to disable averaging
net_avg_samples 2

# Force UTF8? note that UTF8 support required XFT
override_utf8_locale yes

# Add spaces to keep things from moving about?  This only affects certain objects.
use_spacer none

TEXT
${if_running rhythmbox}
${else}
SYSTEM ${hr 2}
${voffset 2}${font OpenLogos:size=16}u${font}   Kernel:  ${alignr}${kernel}
${font StyleBats:size=16}A${font}   CPU: ${cpu}% ${alignr}${cpubar cpu0 8,60}
${font StyleBats:size=16}g${font}   RAM: $memperc% ${alignr}${membar 8,60}
${font StyleBats:size=16}j${font}   SWAP: $swapperc% ${alignr}${swapbar 8,60}
${font Webdings:size=16}~${font}  Battery: ${battery_percent BAT1}% ${alignr}${battery_bar 8,60 BAT1}
${font StyleBats:size=16}q${font}   Uptime: ${alignr}${uptime}
${font StyleBats:size=16}k${font}   Processes: ${alignr}$processes ($running_processes running)

Highest CPU $alignr CPU% MEM%
${hr 1}
${top name 1}$alignr${top cpu 1}${top mem 1}
${top name 2}$alignr${top cpu 2}${top mem 2}
${top name 3}$alignr${top cpu 3}${top mem 3}

HD ${hr 2}
${font Pie charts for maps:size=14}7${font}   ${voffset -5}Home:
${voffset 4}${fs_free /home}/${fs_size /home} ${alignr}${fs_bar 8,60 /home}
${font Pie charts for maps:size=14}7${font}

NETWORK ${hr 2}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlan0}
${voffset -6}${font PizzaDude Bullets:size=14}O${font}   Up: ${upspeed wlan0} kb/s ${alignr}${upspeedgraph wlan0 8,60}
${voffset 4}${font PizzaDude Bullets:size=14}U${font}   Down: ${downspeed wlan0} kb/s ${alignr}${downspeedgraph wlan0 8,60}
${voffset 4}${font PizzaDude Bullets:size=14}N${font}   Upload: ${alignr}${totalup wlan0}
${voffset 4}${font PizzaDude Bullets:size=14}T${font}   Download: ${alignr}${totaldown wlan0}
${voffset 4}${font PizzaDude Bullets:size=14}Z${font}   Signal: ${wireless_link_qual wlan0}% ${alignr}${wireless_link_bar 8,60 wlan0}
${voffset 4}${font PizzaDude Bullets:size=14}a${font}   Local Ip: ${alignr}${addr wlan0}
${voffset 4}${font PizzaDude Bullets:size=14}b${font}   Public Ip: ${alignr}${execi 1 ~/.conky/ip.sh}${else}
${font PizzaDude Bullets:size=14}4${font}   Network Unavailable
${endif}
${endif}
```

Comment: Have you tried using different own_window_type? normal, desktop, panel, dock, override ? If you start conky from terminal what messages does conky output? (or alternatively look for those messages in `~/.xsession-errors` .

Answer (score 0):

I use **conky-manager** which is available through  https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ppa this ppa

it contains a nice set of conky's and you may add more to them by putting your conkyrc: in folder **conky-manager/themes/{your conky name}/config/conkyrc**. for example **conky-manager/themes/clock/config/conkyrc**

i have used it for months and **it never created any problems with any other program**.though there are few minor problems(sometimes conky's don't start automatically) but they would be fixed soon.

official website of conky-manager http://www.teejeetech.in/p/conky-manager.html

### how to install conky-manager

1.Run the following commands in a terminal window:

> sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install conky-manager

2.then run

> sudo apt-get install conky-manager

3.also try this third party conky set.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/5yb5ambg6h4jack/Deluxe_Conky_Theme_Pack.cmtp.7z